# Using sed to replace value in lines, between specific line number range in a file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to implement a bash script to replace a portion of a log file, only in specific line number range.

Example log.txt,
Lines 10-13

```
xxxx: Frame=4, Tag=0, Type=6, SubType=1, Score=0.475311, Scale=1.000000 (yyy)
xxxx: Frame=8, Tag=0, Type=6, SubType=1, Score=0.475311, Scale=1.000000 (yyy)
xxxx: Frame=3, Tag=0, Type=6, SubType=1, Score=0.475311, Scale=1.000000 (yyy)
xxxx: Frame=1, Tag=0, Type=6, SubType=1, Score=0.475311, Scale=1.000000 (yyy)
```

I would like sed to only find and replace these Frame= values between lines 10-13 in the file, with e.g. Frame=1 for all.

Desired output:

```
xxxx: Frame=1, Tag=0, Type=6, SubType=1, Score=0.475311, Scale=1.000000 (yyy)
xxxx: Frame=1, Tag=0, Type=6, SubType=1, Score=0.475311, Scale=1.000000 (yyy)
xxxx: Frame=1, Tag=0, Type=6, SubType=1, Score=0.475311, Scale=1.000000 (yyy)
xxxx: Frame=1, Tag=0, Type=6, SubType=1, Score=0.475311, Scale=1.000000 (yyy)
```

How can I achieve this?
Any help is greately appreciated.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the line numbers in commas

```
sed "10,13s/Frame=[[:digit:]]\+/Frame=1/" data.txt
```